# React: Axios doesn't post to database

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a draggable list with React using [Beautiful Drag-and-drop](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd) and it's working. Now I want to register the final position of the dragged elements in my MYSQL database and I'm using Laravel to manage the backend and the controller.

So far I managed to put everything on place thanks to [this video that I followed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AMBqcJ7tykI&list=PLkZU2rKh1mT8XhRiPQXiGmK6XwnhYfgQc&index=12&ab_channel=AmitavRoy), **but when I'm using `axios.post`, the new data isn't registered in my database**.

When doing a   `console.log({order});`  &   `console.log(response);` , the data is indeed modified as the following :

```
{order: Array(3)}
order: Array(3)
0: {id: 2, order: 1}
1: {id: 3, order: 2}
2: {id: 1, order: 3}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

And

```
{data: "", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {url: "http://localhost:8000/api/social/reorder/", method: "post", data: "{"order":[{"id":2,"order":1},{"id":3,"order":2},{"id":1,"order":3}]}", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), …}
data: ""
headers: {cache-control: "no-cache, private", content-type: "text/html; charset=UTF-8"}
request: XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, onreadystatechange: ƒ, …}
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
```

My functions :

```
  function handleOnDragEnd(result) {
    if (!result.destination) return;
    const items = Array.from(list);
    let oldIndex = result.source.index;
    let newIndex = result.destination.index;
    const [reorderedItem] = items.splice(oldIndex, 1);
    items.splice(newIndex, 0, reorderedItem);
    setList(items);
    
    console.log(oldIndex,newIndex)
    console.log(items)
   

function handleChangeOrder(oldIndex, newIndex) {
     if(oldIndex == newIndex){return ;}
  const items = Array.from(list);
  let newSequence = [];
  items.forEach((item, index) => {
      newSequence.push({ id: item.id, order: index + 1 });
  });
  changeSocialOrder(newSequence);  
  // console.log(newSequence)
}


async function changeSocialOrder(order){
     
try {
  const response = await  axios.post('http://localhost:8000/api/social/reorder/', {order});
  console.log({order});
  console.log(response);
  return response.data;

} catch (error){
  console.error("Not able");
}

}
```

I'm passing my functions to a children hence the usage of `props`, meaning on `onDragEnd` both functions execute :

```
 <DragDropContext onDragEnd={(result, oldIndex, newIndex)=>{ props.handleOnDragEnd(result); props.handleChangeOrder(oldIndex,newIndex) }}>
```

My line in `api.php` file where the routes are :

```
Route::post('/social/reorder', [SocialController::class, 'reorder']);
```

My controller of reorder :

```
public function reorder(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,['order'=>'required|array']);
        $order = $request->input('order');

        DB::transaction(function () use ($order){
            foreach ($order as $value){
                Social::find($value['id'])->update(['order'=>$value['order']]);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer and write your code more cleanly with the component structure becuase the functions dont seem related.

Comment: @Eddsters The initial component is very long and I tried to make it a short as possible. For explanation, `handleOnDragEnd` is to set the last dragged element on place so he doesn't move back, `handleChangeOrder` is to set the new order of the elements on an array,  and finally `changeSocialOrder` to post the result to the database.